# « Une solution multi-plateforme[s] » avec ou sans « s » ?

Tags: adjectifs, accord, préfixes

Je me pose la question suivante :

Est-ce que ça s'accorde avec solution ? ou *multi* indiquant la pluralité des plateformes, dois-je mettre un « s » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce mot étant un adjectif :

> Une solution  multiplateforme sera étudiée.

... on parle ici d'un type de plateforme, mais il n'y a qu'une solution présentée.

> Des solutions multiplateformes seront étudiées.

---

*Évolution de la calligraphie*

1. *[Multiplateforme](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8392688)* peut s'écrire sans `-` depuis 1990.
2. *Multi* ne prend pas de `-` s'il est suivi d'une consonne, ce qui donne pour la graphie ancienne :

> Une solution *multiplate-forme* sera étudiée.
>
> Des solutions *multiplate-formes* seront étudiées.

Comment: Flûte, pas eu le temps de faire une remarque sur la graphie « antienne » qui m’amusait beaucoup.

Comment: @Édouard Origine : *l'antienne* de l'orthographe d'avant et d'après 10 ans avant la fin du 2e millénaire !

Comment: Cela ne répond pas du tout à la question posée. @user7334: pourquoi avoir accepté cette réponse ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Un adjectif s'accorde avec son nom de référence, il y a un exemple singulier (sans `s`) et un pluriel (avec `s`), plus une précision sur la graphie de plate-forme pour pointer l'erreur de positionnement du `-` dans la question ; en quoi est-ce une non réponse ?

Comment: Concernant la remarque de @StéphaneGimenez, je pense qu'une bonne pratique est de commencer par répondre à la question (deux volets : c'est un adjectif, cela s'accorde avec le nom ; _multi_ fait partie du mot et n'est pas la cause du _S_ en terminaison), et seulement ensuite d'apporter des précisions. Rédiger en « entonnoir » est une pratique recommandée en journalisme : d'abord les faits principaux puis les détails. Ceci permet au lecteur de retirer immédiatement les informations qui l'intéressent et de continuer ou non la lecture. On aurait ainsi la réponse en s'arrêtant au premier exemple.

Comment: Pour continuer sur ma lancée précédente, un lecteur trop pressé pourrait croire en s'arrêtant à ton premier exemple que _multiplateforme_ ne s'accorde pas car il sous-entend le _de type_.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai modifié la présentation de ma réponse comme l'a suggéré Chop.

Comment: @Chop Merci de votre lecture qui m'a permis de reformuler ma réponse